# question on two-square problem.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $A_1, A_2$ be two quadratic residues of ($4k + 3$)-prime $p$ that satifsy $0 < A_1 < A_2 < p$. Prove that

$A_1 + A_2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is impossible. Illustrate this result with $p = 23$.

what I think:
Theorem: If $p$ is a ($4k+1$) prime there exist $x,y$ in $N$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = p$.

Suppose $x,y < p^{1/2}$

$x^2 \equiv A_1 \pmod p$
$y^2 \equiv A_2 \pmod p$

$x^2 + y^2 \equiv A_1 + A_2 \pmod p$

If $p\mid A_1 + A_2$ then $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ then $x^2 + y^2 = mp$ for some m in N. since $x,y < p^{1/2}$ only $m=1$ is possible. by theorem, p is $4k+1$, but p is $4k+3$ from our assumption, so p does not divide ($A_1 + A_2$).
So p does not divide $A_1 + A_2$. Hence $A_1 + A_2 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ is impossible.

I am not sure that is correct. Please help me out.

Comment: The theorem says, **if** $p=4k+1$, so you can't use it to **conclude** that $p=4k+1$. In fact, you don't want to use that theorem at all. Also, it's not clear what the point is of the congruence for $2x^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\left(\frac{A_1}p\right)=1$, then $\left(\frac{-A_1}p\right)=\left(\frac{-1}p\right)\left(\frac{A_1}p\right)=-1\cdot1$ since $\left(\frac{-1}p\right)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }p\equiv1\pmod4\\-1&\text{if }p\equiv3\pmod4\end{cases}$. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol